# Label doesn't show any text until the function is finished VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, download, label

Well I have this code: http://pastebin.com/ECrKGp5y

When I click a button that call this function it has to show a Label as you can see in the code.. But until the function isn't finish, the label remains hidden.

The function has to Download some files.. So this function lasts quite...

Comment: have you figured this thing out ?

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method in a Windows form, it is executed in the same thread as the form itself. Thus the form "freezes" until the method finishes. We don't perceive that when the method takes only a few milisseconds to run, but if you have to download something in there, I suggest you use threading.

A good approach for a responsive UI is keeping the code that goes in the same thread as the UI down to a minimum. In your case, you may want to run the bulk of your logic with a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) so that your UI is not blocked. You can then update the label's text either before or after the download, without having to wait for the download to finish.

You may google for some tutorials on how to use that class. I suggest one: http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker

Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you use **BackGroundWorker** .. but if you still in your code, it mostly done with

```
labelestado.Visible = True
Application.DoEvents()
```